# Склеивание результата выборки

Tags: sql, mysql

**Добрый день!**

Разбираю склеивание результата запроса, т.е. делаем выборку по столбам и объединяем их в одно поле. В инете нашел рекомендации - делать с CONCAT, c примером

```
CONCAT (`aa` , `aaa` , `aaaa`)
```

Не могу передалть, как склеть результат выборки:

```
SELECT `Login`, `Password` FROM `DB`
```

Будут 2 колонки. 
Как их объединить в одну ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CONCAT (`login`, `password`) as login_password FROM `table`
```

А зачем ?

Или я не понял вопроса ?

Comment: Согласен с таким методом, пробовал.
А как пробелы внутри поставить? 
И еще вопрос - как например, вместо значения пароля выводить в объединение первый символ и "." в конце ?

Comment: Пример условный. Изучаю MySQL в ускоренном режиме.

Comment: SELECT CONCAT (`login`, ' ', `password`) as login_password FROM `table` - пробел

Comment: По мне так проще выучить SQL в ускоренном режиме и танцевать от этого.

Comment: SELECT CONCAT(login, ' ', LEFT(password,1), '.') as login_password FROM table

"А как пробелы внутри поставить?
И еще вопрос - как например, вместо значения пароля выводить в объединение первый символ и "." в конце ?"

Comment: Работает! :)

Comment: SELECT CONCAT (login, ' фигня с пробелом ', password, ' ещё одна фигня', ' и это тоже фигня') as login_password FROM table

Comment: А как в поле password получить первый символ его и добавить к нему точку?  Копошусь в строковых функциях, пока не то(

Comment: ну вот же было  


SELECT CONCAT(login, ' ', LEFT(password,1), '.') as login_password FROM table

Comment: Конкатенация в разных sql-ах сделана очень по-разному

Answer (score -1):

Заработал вариант:

```
SELECT CONCAT(`FamName`, ' ', LEFT(`Name`,1),'.' , ' ', LEFT(`FamFamName`, 1),'.') AS `User Name` from `userprofilesasp`;
```

Синтаксис: `LEFT(`Колонка`, Кол-во символов слева), '.'` 
**Всем спасибо!**